# How to best store the Google Web Ngram data?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, storage

This is a continuation of [How to best store Google ngrams in a database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/how-to-best-store-google-ngrams-in-a-database), which covers how to store the [Google Ngram Book data](http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets).

I'm looking to store the [Google NGram Web data](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html), which is slightly different in format (no page/year info; just counts):

```
...
ceramics collectables collectibles 55
ceramics collectables fine 130
...
serve as the incoming 92
serve as the incubator 99
```

Since this is a very simple data structure, what is a good method for storing this data that is reasonably quick to import, and quick to retrieve the count by a particular ngram?

I like the idea of a relational db, simply because of the common methods for accessing it, but I'm guessing most of these other non-relation db's (e.g. tokyo hashtable) have pretty common methods as well.

**Update**

Examples of a queries:

```
# primary query
> SELECT ngram_count FROM ngram_table WHERE ngram = 'ceramics collectables fine';

ceramics collectables collectibles 55
ceramics collectables fine 130

# secondary query (not needed, but nice if have option)
SELECT ngram_count FROM ngram_table WHERE ngram LIKE '%collectables%';

ceramics collectables collectibles 55
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you are querying the data?  When you say "count by a particular n-gram", could you give an example (pseudo-query and output)?

Comment: @Nick - example queries added

Comment: A straight-up table will do fine for your first query and full-text indexing will be required for your second query (which I would then rewrite using the appropriate full-text syntax instead of LIKE). So if you're using MySQL that table would have to use MyISAM as its storage engine to enable use of MySQL's full-text features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the script you need right here

```
USE test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ngram_key;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ngram_rec;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ngram_blk;
CREATE TABLE ngram_key
(
    NGRAM_ID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NGRAM VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (NGRAM),
    KEY (NGRAM_ID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=FIXED PARTITION BY KEY(NGRAM) PARTITIONS 256;
CREATE TABLE ngram_rec
(
    NGRAM_ID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    NGRAM_COUNT SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (NGRAM_ID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
CREATE TABLE ngram_blk
(
    NGRAM VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    NGRAM_COUNT SMALLINT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=BLACKHOLE;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER populate_ngram AFTER INSERT ON ngram_blk FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE NEW_ID BIGINT;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO ngram_key (NGRAM) VALUES (NEW.NGRAM);
    SELECT NGRAM_ID INTO NEW_ID FROM ngram_key WHERE NGRAM=NEW.NGRAM;
    INSERT IGNORE INTO ngram_rec VALUES (NEW_ID,NEW.NGRAM_COUNT);
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
INSERT INTO ngram_blk VALUES
('rolando',85),
('pamela',86),
('dominique',87),
('diamond',88),
('rolando edwards',185),
('pamela edwards',186),
('dominique edwards',187),
('diamond edwards',188),
('rolando angel edwards',285),
('pamela claricia edwards',286),
('dominique sharlisee edwards',287),
('diamond ashley edwards',288);
SELECT * FROM ngram_key;
SELECT * FROM ngram_rec;
SELECT A.ngram NGram,B.* FROM 
ngram_key A,ngram_rec B
WHERE A.ngram IN ('rolando angel edwards','rolando edwards','rolando')
AND A.ngram_id=B.ngram_id;
```

here is what the sample data generates:

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ngram_key;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ngram_rec;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ngram_blk;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE ngram_key
    -> (
    ->     NGRAM_ID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     NGRAM VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (NGRAM),
    ->     KEY (NGRAM_ID)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=FIXED PARTITION BY KEY(NGRAM) PARTITIONS 256;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.53 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE ngram_rec
    -> (
    ->     NGRAM_ID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->     NGRAM_COUNT SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (NGRAM_ID)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE ngram_blk
    -> (
    ->     NGRAM VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    ->     NGRAM_COUNT SMALLINT NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=BLACKHOLE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER populate_ngram AFTER INSERT ON ngram_blk FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE NEW_ID BIGINT;
    ->     INSERT IGNORE INTO ngram_key (NGRAM) VALUES (NEW.NGRAM);
    ->     SELECT NGRAM_ID INTO NEW_ID FROM ngram_key WHERE NGRAM=NEW.NGRAM;
    ->     INSERT IGNORE INTO ngram_rec VALUES (NEW_ID,NEW.NGRAM_COUNT);
    -> END; $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> INSERT INTO ngram_blk VALUES
    -> ('rolando',85),
    -> ('pamela',86),
    -> ('dominique',87),
    -> ('diamond',88),
    -> ('rolando edwards',185),
    -> ('pamela edwards',186),
    -> ('dominique edwards',187),
    -> ('diamond edwards',188),
    -> ('rolando angel edwards',285),
    -> ('pamela claricia edwards',286),
    -> ('dominique sharlisee edwards',287),
    -> ('diamond ashley edwards',288);
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM ngram_key;
+----------+-----------------------------+
| NGRAM_ID | NGRAM                       |
+----------+-----------------------------+
|       11 | dominique sharlisee edwards |
|        1 | rolando                     |
|        9 | rolando angel edwards       |
|        4 | diamond                     |
|        8 | diamond edwards             |
|        2 | pamela                      |
|        3 | dominique                   |
|        6 | pamela edwards              |
|        5 | rolando edwards             |
|       12 | diamond ashley edwards      |
|        7 | dominique edwards           |
|       10 | pamela claricia edwards     |
+----------+-----------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM ngram_rec;
+----------+-------------+
| NGRAM_ID | NGRAM_COUNT |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |          85 |
|        2 |          86 |
|        3 |          87 |
|        4 |          88 |
|        5 |         185 |
|        6 |         186 |
|        7 |         187 |
|        8 |         188 |
|        9 |         285 |
|       10 |         286 |
|       11 |         287 |
|       12 |         288 |
+----------+-------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT A.ngram NGram,B.* FROM
    -> ngram_key A,ngram_rec B
    -> WHERE A.ngram IN ('rolando angel edwards','rolando edwards','rolando')
    -> AND A.ngram_id=B.ngram_id;
+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
| NGram                 | NGRAM_ID | NGRAM_COUNT |
+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
| rolando               |        1 |          85 |
| rolando angel edwards |        9 |         285 |
| rolando edwards       |        5 |         185 |
+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: ngram_key has a non unique key on ngram. it seems your trigger has no garuntees the selected ngram id will be that of the most recent insert. at the same time it seems you want ngram to be unique and use last_insert_id().  wrap the second insert in an if to make sure the last insert id wasn't null.

Comment: Turned out the SMALLINT was a bad choice for the Ngram_Count field :P.. Didn't realize until after running my import.  Good times. Speaking of imports, currently I'm simply doing a LOAD DATA INFILE for each of the 100 or so csv files Google provided.  Let me know if you have a suggestion on faster importing. Thanks again

Comment: Are you loading all 5-grams, or what? How faster are queries and how much RAM do you have? I'm curious before I try this for myself.